# Rvalue reference to lvalue reference

Tags: c++11, reference, rvalue-reference

Rvalues cannot be used to initialize lvalue (normal) references. But if I write a helper conversion function, it works. What is going on in the background and is it possibly dangerous?

```
template <class T>
inline T& getLvalueRef(T&& x)
{
    return x;
}
```

The compiler accepts this.

And then

```
int ten = 10;
int& ref = getLvalueRef(ten+8);

// use some variables to rewrite memory
int a = 7;
int b = 10;
int c = (a+b)*6;

// check if still works
cout << ref << endl; // okay, still 18
ref = 9;
cout << ref << endl; // okay, 9
```

Comment: As far as I can see `ref` references the stack variable x inside `getLvalueRef`, which disappears before `ref` does. I believe the '//use some variables to rewrite memory` failed. Not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code invokes undefined behaviour. `ten+8` creates a temporary, whose lifetime ends at the end of the *full-expression* in which it appears (in your case, the semicolon). `getLvalueRef` then returns a reference to this temporary.

Any usage of this reference past the *full-expression* in which `ten+8` was created is not allowed.

Comment: Note however that it is the use of `getLvalueRef` not the function that caused the problem.

Comment: Thanks.

1) As I understand, it may make sense to wrap a temporary with such a helper function to pass it to some library function that wants to deal with a non-const reference for some reason (of course I don't mean output parameters).

2) It seems from your explanation that actually an `int&` or `SomeType&` can refer to an rvalue. So my `int& ref` actually refers to that temporary, even though it seems to be an lvalue reference. Maybe the terminology is misleading and int& is just a "reference", but one that doesn't automatically accept rvalue assignments.