# Rvalue reference to lvalue reference - ub?

Tags: c++, c++17

This is not a duplicate of [Rvalue reference to lvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23629745/rvalue-reference-to-lvalue-reference)

Since I'm asking this for C++17: does the following still invoke undefined behavior (if the reference is used, of course) due to a dangling reference?

```
template <typename T>
constexpr T& to_lvalue(T&& r) noexcept { return r; }
int main()
{
    int ten = 10;
    int& ref = to_lvalue(ten+8);
    // Is ref a dangling reference in C++17?
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Yes, nothing has changed in that regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the reference dangles. There was some talk about possibly extending the lifetime-extension system to some additional cases, but AFAIK nothing was actually done for C++17.